# Hot code push is breaking application

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, meteor

I am building an application in meteor and trying to deploy it to iOS. Everything goes great up until a certain point. I can build my application and put it onto the device. I can run the application and everything works as expected.

Now the weird part:

When I push a new version of the application to the server (hosted on digital ocean, not the free meteor.com server), it pulls all of the new assets (I've watched it in the js debug console in the simulator) and then goes blank white. It also gives an error that it cannot parse some of the files. I inspected the DOM and clicked on the css and js files. They are the same html as the index file, but broken in different ways. Css is only affected when I update css files. Js is only affected when I update js files.

I can fix this problem by deleting the application and reinstalling it, but this is HIGHLY undesirable for my users. They will not know to do that if the application all of a sudden goes blank. I would like to continue using hot code push to update the application, so abandoning it altogether is not an option.

Now even weirder stuff:

The meteor build process concatenates and minifies all of the css and js for your project, slaps a unique name on it and puts it into the applications index.html file. When I perform an update to the server, the index.html file doesn't change! It remains the same as the old file. Same unique identifiers for the css and js.

My theory:

The `index.html` file (or at least the unique identifiers for concatenated and minified css and js files) are being cached somewhere and not updated when hot code push happens.

I have looked into issues on GitHub about this and have found a similar one [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4038).

Below is the ACTUAL 'js' file being served by application after hot code push (You will not that it is not js, but semi-broken html which is a copy of the `index.html`).

I know that this html is malformatted.
That is my problem, I did not write it. It is automatically built by meteor.
This is exactly how it came from the built product.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html >
< html >
< head >
< meta charset = "utf-8" >
< meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no" >
< meta name = "viewport" content = "user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" >
< meta name = "msapplication-tap-highlight" content = "no" >
< link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" class = "__meteor-css__" href = "/ea9d1dad4a77431e53e11a9fc699dfac92346452.css?meteor_css_resource=true" >
< script type = "text/javascript" >
__meteor_runtime_config__ = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent("%7B%22meteorRelease%22%3A%22METEOR%401.1.0.2%22%2C%22PUBLIC_SETTINGS%22%3A%7B%22othersetting%22%3A%22anothervalue%22%7D%2C%22ROOT_URL%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fnbt.otterhive.com%2F%22%2C%22ROOT_URL_PATH_PREFIX%22%3A%22%22%2C%22autoupdateVersion%22%3A%226705fea274dc86fd9c030412dd1f67bdfb4764d1%22%2C%22autoupdateVersionRefreshable%22%3A%227bcd7c6202871dd5313c15a8b87da110997f2c80%22%2C%22autoupdateVersionCordova%22%3A%2246143d47225e20f616f663860b06e155b01a6107%22%2C%22DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fnbt.otterhive.com%2F%22%7D"));

if (/Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    // When Android app is emulated, it cannot connect to localhost,
    // instead it should connect to 10.0.2.2
    // (unless we're using an http proxy; then it works!)
    if (!__meteor_runtime_config__.httpProxyPort) {
        __meteor_runtime_config__.ROOT_URL = (__meteor_runtime_config__.ROOT_URL || '').replace(/localhost/i, '10.0.2.2');
        __meteor_runtime_config__.DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL = (__meteor_runtime_config__.DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL || '').replace(/localhost/i, '10.0.2.2');
    }
}
< /script>
< script type = "text/javascript" src = "/cordova.js"></script>
< script type = "text/javascript" src = "/e2c72dd7569f33c0169c66320f3f1e60cce07f3d.js"></script>

< meta charset = "utf-8" >
< meta http - equiv = "X-UA-Compatible" content = "IE=edge" >
< meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" >
< title > Nature Based Therapeutics < /title>
< /head>
< body >

< /body>
< /html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" class="__meteor-css__" href="/ea9d1dad4a77431e53e11a9fc699dfac92346452.css?meteor_css_resource=true">

  <script type="text/javascript">
    __meteor_runtime_config__ = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent("%7B%22meteorRelease%22%3A%22METEOR%401.1.0.2%22%2C%22PUBLIC_SETTINGS%22%3A%7B%22othersetting%22%3A%22anothervalue%22%7D%2C%22ROOT_URL%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fnbt.otterhive.com%2F%22%2C%22ROOT_URL_PATH_PREFIX%22%3A%22%22%2C%22autoupdateVersion%22%3A%226705fea274dc86fd9c030412dd1f67bdfb4764d1%22%2C%22autoupdateVersionRefreshable%22%3A%227bcd7c6202871dd5313c15a8b87da110997f2c80%22%2C%22autoupdateVersionCordova%22%3A%2246143d47225e20f616f663860b06e155b01a6107%22%2C%22DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fnbt.otterhive.com%2F%22%7D"));

    if (/Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
      // When Android app is emulated, it cannot connect to localhost,
      // instead it should connect to 10.0.2.2
      // (unless we're using an http proxy; then it works!)
      if (!__meteor_runtime_config__.httpProxyPort) {
        __meteor_runtime_config__.ROOT_URL = (__meteor_runtime_config__.ROOT_URL || '').replace(/localhost/i, '10.0.2.2');
        __meteor_runtime_config__.DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL = (__meteor_runtime_config__.DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL || '').replace(/localhost/i, '10.0.2.2');
      }
    }
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/e2c72dd7569f33c0169c66320f3f1e60cce07f3d.js"></script>


  <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Nature Based Therapeutics</title>
</head>

<body>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are the spaces in tags, `< html >`

Comment: Most of those added spaces have no effect on how the HTML is parsed. This one, however: `<meta http - equiv="` is a bad idea. Use `<meta http-equiv="`

Comment: @Cerbrus Please do not edit the html as that was the actual code being displayed in the html inspector. The malformed html is part of my problem. The meteor application has an index.html file. It is perfectly formatted. It has a script tag in it pointing to the js loader file. When I open that resource, it should be a js file, but instead it is a broken html file. I did not put any spaces in this html file. I never wrote or even touched this html file. It was generated by the meteor build process.

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm sorry, I should have explained. The broken html should be the js and the valid html is the html from index.html. They are not the same code. They appear to be the same code, but they are both from different files. Which makes it even weirder. See [this issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4038), I think other's have been having a similar issue. But I have been able to consistently reproduce this one.